# JSON.stringify only super class fields

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, super, stringify

I would like to use `JSON.stringify(object)` to serialize an object to send it over the network.

As I use the same code base for backend and frontend I have a super class that is used by both and special implementations for the front- and backend.

When I `JSON.stringify(object)` on the object, all fields are serialized.

I tried to assign the object to an empty object of the super-class, but that copied the fields as well and didn't help.

```
const commonObject: CommonObject = new CommonObject(null, null, null);

Object.assign(commonObject, localObject); 

JSON.stringify(commonObject);
```

Is there a way to maybe use the replacer function that returns `undefined` for all fields not present in the super class? I'm unsure how I'd be able to get the fields at runtime. Is this possible?

I'm sorry if some of the terms are not used in this way in a node, typescript, javascript world. I originally come from a java background.

Comment: I would suggest creating a constructor for your object that accepts as an argument the result of `JSON.parse()`.  Then, the constructor can copy over just the properties that it wants to properly initialize itself as a full-fledged object of your type.  I'd also suggest you not directly `JSON.stringify()` your class instance, but rather create a `.toJSON()` method that stringifies just what is needed to be saved rather than stringifying the whole object.  Objects often have local state that isn't appropriate for long term storage, particularly if they have references to other object.

Comment: Doing both the stringify and the construction the way I suggested gives you total control over how it's stringified and how it's initialized, even giving you the ability to adapt when your object gets modified in the future and has newer properties that might not be saved in older version of the object.

Comment: @jfriend00 Are you saying that I should use `JSON.parse()` on the receiving end? If so, that is not suitable for me for two reasons: 1. It increases network traffic, without any purpose. 2. I don't want the client to ever receive that information.

Comment: What are you using `JSON.stringify()` for, if you're not going to use `JSON.parse()` somewhere?  That makes no sense.  The entire point of `JSON.stringify()` is to create a JSON string representation of a Javascript object with all of it's properties and that's only ever useful if someone calls `JSON.parse()` on it at some point to do something with the JSON.  Perhaps if you showed a more complete version of what the code is trying to do, we could understand better what you're asking for help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do use `JSON.parse()` but on the other end of the network pipe. Not all fields need to be transferred, only those in the super class are relevant for the frontend. Edit: Just realized my previous comment might have been a little confusing. I meant the constructor with `JSON.parse()` in the frontend is already there, but that won't fix the increased traffic.

Comment: So, then use my suggestion to use a constructor on your super class and pass it either the unparsed JSON (which is can call `JSON.parse()` on to create a temporary object) or a temporary object from the already parsed JSON and the superclass can then dip into that info and grab only the properties that it needs.  Don't blindly use `Object.assign()` to copy everything when you KNOW that is has more properties that you want or may have more properties than you want.  Just a matter of writing code that grabs just the properties your object wants.

Comment: Of, if you want to only `stringify` some of the properties for network efficiency, then create a superclass method `.superToJSON()` that manually creates a temporary object with just the super class properties on it you want to send and call `JSON.stringify()` on that temporary object and send that across the network.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand what you're asking.

To stringify only the superclass part of an object, I would suggest that you create a `.superToJSON()` method and in that method, you create a temporary object, copy over to it just the properties you want to serialize and then call `JSON.stringify()` on that temporary object.  This way you control precisely what is stringified.  I wouldn't attempt to use the `replacer` feature for this.  Plus, something like this is probably better coded where you consciously decide what is included in the serialization rather than what is excluded.

You can then send that to the client and it will be able to use that to assign to a super class instance.

As an example:

```
class someClass {
    superToJson() {
        const temp = {
            propA: this.propA,
            propB: this.propB
        };
        return JSON.stringify(temp);
    }
}
```

Or, if you have a lot of properties, you can make a list of them and use a utility funciton:

```
function copyProps(target, source, listOfProps) {
   for (let prop of listOfProps) {
       target[prop] = source[prop];
   }
   return target;
}

class someClass {
    superToJson() {
        const temp = copyProps({}, this, ["propA", "propB", "propC"]);
        return JSON.stringify(temp);
    }
}
```

In Javascript, there is no automatic way to do this because there is no notion of which properties belong to which superClass or baseClass or whatever. They are all just properties on the same object with no specific origin recorded or known regardless of which part of the class hierarchy originally assigned them.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'd like to accomplish. So there is no way to receive a list of all properties of the superclass programatically? Having to list the relevant props seems like it would be easy to forget to update some day?

Comment: Adding a replacer function to `JSON.stringify` with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(basicCommonObject).includes(key)` seems to work, where `basicCommonObject` is just an instance of `CommonObject`. Would this also work without a specific instance?

Comment: @Jojomatik - No, it wouldn't work without an instance.  A class doesn't have any of the data properties on it as those are only added when the constructor runs and you initialize those properties.  I actually like having to specifically list/determine the properties I want serialized because I regular have objects that have live, run-time state that doesn't belong in the serialization (such as references to other objects).  I understand your comment about maintenance, but I worry as much about maintenance when you auto-serialize every property too as that's not always what you want.

Comment: @Jojomatik - I see your question is tagged as TypeScript.  The TypeScript compiler knows somewhere what properties a class has as you have to declare that, right?  But, that info is gone once it's compiled to plain Javascript.  I don't know enough about TypeScript to know if there's any way you can leverage its knowledge of the declared properties in your class.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to research this (if typescript somehow includes this information in javascript) further and - if that's okay for you - amend your answer.